PayPal Authorize/Capture increase amount
When taking delayed capture of funds, payment gateways normally have the standard 115% increase limit. PayPal mention this a lot in their documentation, too. However, we are getting this error: "MAX_CAPTURE_AMOUNT_EXCEEDED" with details: "Capture amount exceeds allowable limit. Please contact customer service or your account manager to request the change to your overage limit. The default overage limit is 115%, which allows the sum of all captures to be up to 115% of the order amount. Local regulations (e.g. in PSD2 countries) prohibit overages above the amount authorized by the payer."
We get this error when the capture amount increases even by 1p over the authorise amount.
Before I start coding workarounds, I wanted to check this is definitely the case. Has anyone else experienced this? We are in food retail, so sometimes the weight of items increases from point of order to point of dispatch, so we have to increase the amount (it's in our T&Cs). Why do PayPal not do the industry standard 115% anymore?

Not tested recently but as far as I'm aware 115% is still the default except for PSD2 country payers

I'm in a PSD2 country (UK), but that's my point. The other 2 payment gateways I've integrated (within the UK) stick to the 115% limit, but PayPal have a 100% limit, which seems incongruous.

It is definitely the case. PayPal's overcapture requirements for PSD2 buyer countries are covered in this guide.
Basically it has to do with the Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) requirement. If you modify the total, the buyer must be sent back to PayPal to re-approve the new amount with SCA.

Thanks for your reply. I've seen this guide, and I suppose it does answer my initial question. However,  2 other payment gateways I've integrated (within the UK) stick to the 115% limit, but PayPal have a 100% limit, which seems incongruous.
